# What happened when user clicked "Upload" from index page?

Tags: python, html, flask

I'm studying some code from this repository of Liu Lixiang and I'm wondering how it actually works.

The source is here: https://gist.github.com/liulixiang1988/cc3093b2d8cced6dcf38

Firstly, when I get to the main page (index.html). It will prompt me a page where I upload my files.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
      <div class="header">
        <h3 class="text-muted">How To Upload a File</h3>
      </div>
      <hr/>
      <div>

      <form action="upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" multiple="" name="file[]" class="span3" /><br />
        <input type="submit" value="Upload"  class="span2">
      </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

When I click "Submit", how does it action link me to the function upload() in app.py to process the files?

Thanks guys.

Comment: It makes a POST request to the endpoint `upload`. How that is handled is an othercquestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The routing is done based upon the `action` given

```
<form action="upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" multiple="" name="file[]" class="span3" /><br />
<input type="submit" value="Upload"  class="span2">
</form>
```

Here the action is defined as upload, so flask looks for any function/ url linked with the action upload.

```
<form action="upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

in app.py you can find a function with name action thus executing the function there

```
@app.route('/upload', methods=['POST'])
def upload():
```

this also can differ with the method you specify. The methods can be GET,POST,PUT.

Based on the method action the functions can be modified

Comment: thank you. does that mean if in the html form I change `action="upload2"` then I should change the name of the function in app.py to `def upload2()` too? Thanks!

Comment: @Kelvin yes. the action is bound with the names

Answer (score 0):

the action in the form is redirecting you to a url /upload via POST-Request:

```
<form action="upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Now, the upload.html in the gist has the /upload route defined:

```
@app.route('/upload', methods=['POST'])
```

And the following code handles the upload, like getting the files from the post request and so on.

Just try a simple page, click submit and you see what's happening:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <form action="upload" method="post">
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Save this as html file, open it in a browser and click submit. You will see in your browser's address bar "upload" as the route goal. The POST-request tries to go to this resource and the upload.html in your example handles this.

In addition, the comments in app.py do some part of the explanation:

```
# We'll render HTML templates and access data sent by POST
# using the request object from flask. Redirect and url_for
# will be used to redirect the user once the upload is done
# and send_from_directory will help us to send/show on the
# browser the file that the user just uploaded
```